# how can i implement authorization in a dotnet api integrating firebase?

Tags: .net, firebase, api, asp.net-core, firebase-authentication

Currently I generate a custom token using the sdk firebase, even at this point it works well, however I need to validate the authentication with the token that was generated.

I found this implementation in several posts on the internet, but it is not working for me, can someone help me?

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/[FIREBASE-PROJECT]";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/[FIREBASE-PROJECT]",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "[FIREBASE-PROJECT]",
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };
    });
```